# Is GenericResponse best practice for rest API?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

We are designing new rest api and I am conflict which one of the below solution is the best practice/approach for rest API response(the rest APIs are implemented using spring boot) and what is the pros and cons for each one of them ?

**Solution Tow** is about returning data object without any using any envelope ex `ResponseEntity<MyClass>`

**Solution Tow** is about having GenericResponse ex:

```
public class GenericResponse {

private int code;

private APiError error;

private Object data;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if the client needs to show appropriate error message based on backend processing then "Generic response" format with error and data object is helpful. Otherwise only data response with proper status code (200/400/404/403) will help to keep the code simple.

Comment: In solution one, to handle any error or excption, we are using controller advice and return ResponseEntity<ApiError> which contains clear message

Comment: I think this is good too with proper status code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a GenericResponse Model. One of the Pros of using is definitely better maintainability.

Following approach is What I like more and I feel it's more standard

```
     public abstract class BaseResponse {
      private String ResponseCode;
     //Contains common fields Ex. Tracking fields like correlationId, RequestId
     }

     public class ErrorResponse extends BaseResponse {
     //Error Fields
    }

    public class Response extends ErrorResponse {
    //Response 
    }
```

In future, if you're need of adding a new Response for endpoint, you can just extend the ErrorResponse(Common error response structure).